# XSLT - Matching nodes that have that a certain node inside them (like jQuery ":has")

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let's say I have the following XML file

```
<a id="123">
   <b type="foo" value="1" />
   <b type="baz" value="1" />
</a>
<a id="789">
  <b type="bar" value="12" />
</a>
<a id="999">
   <b type="foo", value="2" />
</a>
```

I want to get a list of all the 'a' nodes that have a 'b' subnode with a type="foo" and value="1". You can do something similar in jQuery with the ":has" selector.

For the record I'm planning on using xmlstarlet on the command line (but I'm not married to doing it that way), so a xslt that works that way would be best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like this:

```
a[b[@type='foo'][@value='1']]
```

should do the trick

Comment: I didn't know you could do node[node[something]], that's an elegant and clean way to do it. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a single XPath expression as pointed out in gizmo's answer.

Because the question is specifically for XSLT, **here is an efficient XSLT solution** using keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<!--                                      --> 
 <xsl:key name="kAByBTypeVal" 
  match="a"
  use="concat(b/@type,'+',b/@value)"/>
<!--                                      -->       
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select=
       "key('kAByBTypeVal', 'bar+12')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
    <a id="123">
        <b type="foo" value="1" />
        <b type="baz" value="1" />
    </a>
    <a id="789">
        <b type="bar" value="12" />
    </a>
    <a id="999">
        <b type="foo" value="2" />
    </a>
</t>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
<a id="789">
  <b type="bar" value="12"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be: /b[@type='foo' and @value=1]/parent::a

Comment: This is not the answer. This XPath expression selects the *top* node and only if its name is "b". The top node is a single node and it never has a parent that is also an element.

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:variable name="nodeList" select="a[b[@type='foo' and @value=1]]"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$nodeList">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You've got the /b[@type='foo' and @value=1]] from Maurice Perry, but it's more complicated and verbose than I was looking for.

Comment: Fair enough if it's more complicated than you want but I did NOT copy it from another SO user

Comment: The OP wants a "list of 'a' nodes"" -- not a list of the string value of the "a" nodes.

Comment: Oh I'm not accusing you of copying. I'm saying that you and Maurice Perry have the same insight, but yours is slightly more complicated.